# JAXA/NASA astronauts on a Shuttle mission; was it like dual citizenship/joint appointment or did one agency take precedent?

Tags: nasa, astronauts, jaxa, regulatory, space-agencies

Professor and former astronaut [Takao Doi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takao_Doi) does many things, including being a Space Shuttle mission specialist, an amateur astronomer and discoverer of two supernovae [2002gw IN NGC 922](http://www.cbat.eps.harvard.edu/iauc/07900/07995.html) and [Supernova 2007aa in NGC 4030](http://www.rochesterastronomy.org/sn2007/sn2007aa.html), and being apparently the [fourth person](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/49321/12102) or the [third person](https://www.flight-toys.com/boomerang/boomnews/spacebooms.html) to throw a boomerang in space and the first to throw one specifically designed to work in microgravity.

Both the Wikipedia biography and the Rochester Astronomy.org page about SN 2007aa mention Doi's "dual citizenship" type association with two space agencies:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takao_Doi):

> Space career: NASA/JAXA Astronaut

[SN 2007aa](http://www.rochesterastronomy.org/sn2007/sn2007aa.html):

> Discovered by Takao Doi (USA/Japan). Note that Takao Doi is not only an amature astronomer, he is also a JAXA/NASA astronaut.

Setting aside the question of whether it's NASA/JAXA or JAXA/NASA, what does this mean? Is it akin to dual citizenship, or an academic joint appointment? Was Doi simultaneously both for an extended period of time or did they have to be one or the other while participating in STS-87 and STS-123?

*During STS missions of that era*, did astronauts report to and follow instructions solely from one space agency or the other, or was there a "chain of command" in that if one agency doesn't say either way, then the other agency has jurisdiction?

Comment: I could probably answer this about shuttle, but the last paragraph being in present tense makes me think you want to know about ISS as well.

Comment: Edited accordingly, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It will likely take me some time to dig up files on this.

Comment: I'm having difficulty locating  sources on this. Some of the intergovernmental agreements are online, but they lay out a rather high-level framework. My recollection is that the international folks we trained to be shuttle mission specialists were always JAXA/CSA/ESA employees, just detailed to the Shuttle Program, but I have not yet found that explicitly stated.

Comment: @OrganicMarble as far as employment/employer/employee aspects, they worked for and were paid by their "home office"?

Comment: Right, just like the astronauts who were still in the US military - they were detailed to NASA.

Comment: @OrganicMarble feel fee to consider writing up even a short answer based on whatever is available. *Thanks!*